# Find average of rows over name ;display all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table with the below values

```html
name    symbol  current value
a       a1      1
a       a2      2
a       a3      4
a       a4      3
a       a5      5
b       b1      6
b       b2      7
b       b3      8
c       c1      1
c       c2      2
c       c3      3
c       c4      3
c       c5      5
d       d1      6
d       d2      6
```

Required : To find the average of the current value grouping by name , yet show all results . ie ; the result show be like below ;

```html
name    symbol  current value   Required
a       a1              1           =current value/(sum of all 'a' current values)
a       a2              2           =current value/(sum of all 'a' current values)
a       a3              4           =current value/(sum of all 'a' current values)
a       a4              3           =current value/(sum of all 'a' current values)
a       a5              5           =current value/(sum of all 'a' current values)
b       b1              6           = current value /(sum of all 'b' current values)
b       b2              7           = current value /(sum of all 'b' current values)
b       b3              8           = current value /(sum of all 'b' current values)
```

Similarly for all names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to a subquery which finds the averages:

```
SELECT t1.*,
    CASE WHEN t2.avg > 0 THEN t1.current_value / t2.avg ELSE 0 END AS avg
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, SUM(current_value) AS avg
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name
) t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

The `CASE` expression is necessary to protect against a possible divide by zero, which could happen if a given `name` happen to have all zero current values.  In that case, I default the average to zero.

Comment: is it possible to find the sum of  "avg" column  as a seperate column, retaining all the rows ? Need to find the further average by selecting only a certain number of rows .

Comment: @Me-si I don't follow your question, but you should probably open up a new question.  Your new requirements would invalidate all the answers already given here.

Answer (score 0):

try this logic :)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_listing_sample
WHERE
    NAME = 'a'
AND NAME = 'b'
ORDER BY
    id
```

Comment: I need to find the average of each entry against the sum(current value) for each name .